# Security Updates - The package system is broken

Tags: 12.04, package-management, updates, dependencies

tried to update recently, and have this result from Update Manager:

> The package system is broken
>
> If you are using third party repositories then disable them, since they are >a common source of problems.
> Now run the following command in a terminal: apt-get install -f
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> libk5crypto3: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.12 is installed
> libk5crypto3:i386: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.12 is installed

Have tried: `apt-get install -f` as suggested

also tried `apt-get clean` & i think `dpkg --configure -a` I also tried after trying to sort the problem with Synaptic, but nothing has made any difference.

I don't have any third party repositories enabled

Any help would be great, thank you!

System is:

Ubuntu Release 12.04 (precise) 64-bit

*following Alexs suggestion:*
Alex, thank you. After `sudo apt-get install -f`  I got

```
Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libk5crypto3 i386 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.7 [77.4 kB]
Fetched 77.4 kB in 0s (173 kB/s)  
dpkg: error processing libk5crypto3:i386 (--configure):
 libk5crypto3:i386 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.6 cannot be configured because libk5crypto3:amd64 is in a different version (1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.7)
dpkg: error processing libk5crypto3 (--configure):
 libk5crypto3:amd64 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.7 cannot be configured because libk5crypto3:i386 is in a different version (1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.6)
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 libk5crypto3:i386
 libk5crypto3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will clean out the local repository of retrieved package files.

`sudo apt-get clean`

Correct for any broken dependencies

`sudo apt-get install -f`

will configure all the packages which haven't been configured yet.

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

After you have done all of that you can run `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: Alex, thank you. Edited my question with the result of your suggestion.